# EF Core 2, .NET CORE 2 :How do I query the same column for multiple conditions using IQueryable<T>?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.2

I have a database table similar to the one in below image

[Table with 2 columns (UserId and value)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTNYW.png)

I will be passing the UserId along with 2 strings. For Ex: **userId: 1**, **key1: h1**, **key2: h2** 
to an APi with a similar signature.

```
Public List<T> CheckValuesForUser(string userId, string key1, string key2)
```

I need to check if the particular userId 1 has both h1 and h2 values. If the User doesnt have both the Keys then the query should return null.

I have tried the below queries,

1. `context.tableName.where(i=> i.value.Equals("h1") && i.value.Equals("h2"))` -- this returns nothing. I assume this predicate is executed for each row.
2. `Context.tableName.Where(i=> new string[]{ Key1,Key2 }.Contains(i.Value))` -- This returns a value even if the user does not have a value for Key2. I need to get a NULL result if the user doesnt have both the keys.
3. `var list1= Context.tableName.Where(i=> i.Value.Equals(key1)).toList(); 
   var list2= Context.tableName.Where(i=> i.Value.Equals(Key2)).toList();
   if(list1.Count > 0 && list2.Count > 0) list1.AddRange(list2);`

Can someone please help me find a better solution? I am using **Asp.Net Core 2.2**

Comment: can you try ``Context.tableName.Where(i=> new string[]{ Key1,Key2 }.All(x=>x == i.Value))``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the h1 & h2 entries are separate records, you will need to check for both of the values independently.

```
// Group the records by the expected UserId
var groupedRecords = context
                     .TableName
                     .Where(t => t.UserId == userId)
                     .GroupBy(t => t.UserId);

// Ensure both the required records exist within the grouping
var hasRequiredRecords = groupedRecords.Any(i => i.Value.Equals("h1"))
                                        && Any(i => i.Value.Equals("h2"))

// Now that you know you have the required values, return them
return groupedRecords.Where(i => i.Value.Equals("h1") && i.Value.Equals("h2");
```

The last line will return only the two records with values `h1` & `h2` for the provided `userId` provided as a single `List<T>`

Comment: It works but I actually needed both the records. So do I get them in 2 variables and merge the result.. When I use concat on IQueryable I run into an exception.

Comment: @Anish I have updated my answer to return the items in the format you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to get what you want :

```
string[] keys = new string[] { key1, key2 };
var result = (from m in context.UserInfo
              where m.UserId == userId && keys.Any(name => name.Equals(m.Value)) select m).ToList().Count < keys.Count() ? null : 
              (from m in context.UserInfo where m.UserId == userId && keys.Any(name => name.Equals(m.Value)) select m).ToList();
```

When the condition is not met, the result is received as null, if it is met, the corresponding data set is returned to the result.